# How did Nicholas Knight become a cop if he couldn't be seen in the day?

Tags: forever-knight

*Forever Knight* was a mid-90s supernatural crime drama surrounding Nicholas Knight, a French-born nobleman turned vampire living in modern times and working as a police officer. As the opening narration states:

> He was "Brought across" in 1228... preyed on humans for their blood. Now, he wishes to be mortal again. To repay society for his sins. To emerge from his world of Darkness. From his endless... Forever Night.

Much like Duncan McCleoud of *Highlander,* a similar supernatural themed action drama series, Nick has lived for hundreds of years, so often he has to move around and change his identity so no one but his few allies catch on to his vampiric nature. However, *unlike* Duncan, Nick has some very suspicious drawbacks; he barely eats human food, *has* to have a supply of blood at particular times, has to keep his "Vamp outs" secret because when in full "dark" mode, fangs appear and his eyes change... but most damning of all, he's "allergic" to sunlight, so can *only* work at night.

Now granted, he *is* a vampire and can "compel" people to do things or change their memories, so it *is* possible he could have just "forged" his police training in the minds of the Police Academy to get his badge... but that would require a *lot* of telepathic mind manipulation on a **lot** of people. And it's not as if he could do the courses "remotely", so he logically would have *had* to go out in the day at *some point,* which could risk his death, if not his exposure.

How then did Nick even *become* a Police Officer? Wouldn't there *need* to be records of him attending Police classes or training during the day?

Comment: Presumably he went to knight school?

Comment: It's possible he forged his original police training records and **transferred** to the new force from another jurisdiction. As I understand it, that is possible.

Comment: He probably claimed to have light sensitivity.

Comment: @Paulie_D That would still mean he'd need a record from the _original_ Precinct, though, and that doesn't excuse his lack of an academy file. It may slow down the process, sure, but Cops come up for review all the time. And considering all the "odd" cases he's involved in, Internal Affairs would likely take a look at him eventually.

Comment: @Valorum That was essentially the "light allergy" I mentioned. And yes, that _is_ a real-life phenomenon, and it shouldn't stop him from working.... but it _would_ bring up the question of _how_ he managed to train to **become** a cop. From my research, a lot of the Academy practice and training happens during daylight hours, so Nick would still need to show he _went_ through it. The question is essentially asking _how_ he sidestepped that process. I can _buy_ him being a cop, and **easily** see him "compelling" his way into the job...but forging the _records_ though? That's a bit tougher...

Comment: @Michael HA! it is t laugh. Good one, dude....

Comment: @Russhiro Consider that he also needs to change his actual *identity* every few decades, lest someone notice that he doesn't seem to be aging.  Birth certificate, SIN, driver's license, etc.  Whether he does this himself or "he knows a guy," he would need to have a reliable means of creating believable documents on a recurring basis.  It also makes sense that the vampire community would have resources for this sort of thing, since all vampires in a given city would need the same treatment.  I don't recall if the series ever touched on this point directly, but he clearly has the means.

Comment: @Russhiro Just to be clear - changing those other identity documents also means registering them with government agencies without anyone noticing the sudden arrival of a new 30-something person.  Accessing government records across various agencies has got to be on par with accessing police records.

Comment: @Steve-O And i grant you that. Just as I grant this was probably a _whole_ lot easier during the time the show's set in (the 1990s) as opposed to doing so now (greater hacking options and technology, tighter IT security protocols, etc.) Oddly enough, "creating" a new persona and getting basic documentation isn't _that_ difficult; it's the level of security and access a Military person, Security personal or *Police officer* needs to have that makes this so daunting. If he was an eccentric, rich private citizen, there'd be fewer worries. Being a _cop_ though, means Nick's under constant scrutiny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So taking [this](https://foreverknight.fandom.com/wiki/Nick_Knight) description of Nick's history along with [this](https://foreverknight.fandom.com/wiki/Flashback_timeline) timeline, it would appear that Nick had been living in Toronto for around a year under the Nick Knight identity (for which he had forged identity documents) before deciding to become a cop.

In this time, he had already befriended the medical examiner Natalie and she knew that he was a vampire.

So he definately didn't go to a Police Academy. There was not enough time between Nick deciding to be a cop and him becoming a detective for him to go through Police Academy and earn a Detective role.

I don't remember the details of how he was able to walk in to a Detective job were ever explicitly given in the series.

That's what we know, so the following is just my own conjecture.

I'd have to assume he used a combination of forged documents (he must have had some contacts in this field to create the Nick Knight identity in the first place) and vampiric persuasion for people to not dig to deep into his past or he used it on whoever he was claiming to have previously worked for.

He used this persuasion on his original police captain to allow him to only work nights and to work without a partner (initially at least), so there is form of him using persuasion on Police higher ups to get what he wants.

This would mean that his forged documents would include, not only identity documents, but police qualifications and some form of job history with another police force.